# undefined method `draw_lines' for Drawer:Module (NoMethodError) in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have created a Module which is supposed to draw.  I have included the Module in my script, and when trying to call a method I get:

```
undefined method `draw_lines' for Draw:Module (NoMethodError) in Ruby
```

Here is the code:

```
module Draw
  def draw_lines
    # stuff. 
  end
end

require './draw'
Draw::draw_lines # undefined method `draw_lines' for Drawer:Module (NoMethodError) in Ruby
```

Also, it would be nice to know, why do we need to do `require './draw'` and it does not let me do just `require 'draw'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you define modules in Ruby the way you want to access it's methods is by declaring the method on the module

```
module Draw
  def Draw.draw_lines
    puts "hello"
  end
end
>> Draw.draw_lines
>> "hello"
```

Further, why you need to write `./Draw` and not just `Draw` is because it's a "path-thing".
But first we need to disect `require` briefly.

`require` lets you load and run a file, but more smartly, than it's sibling `load`, by after loading and running once it won't require/load it again as `load` does.

So `require` takes a path to a Ruby file and that's what the `./` is for, this dot-slash means that you want to require a file from the `same` working directory as your current file is in. 
This could then be expanded to `../` (require from one directory above) and so on!

Hope this helps!